# Name for a type of game to help children get to know each other?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for the name for the whole type/genre of games whose purpose is primarily to help children get to know each other.
It's close in meaning to "party games" but their main goal is to socialise the group.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Naming, including naming programming variables/classes 

Comment: @JeffSahol: I don’t see how it’s about naming, or at least any more than any other single-word-request question.

Answer (score 9):

In the world of EFL (English as a foreign language) or if you prefer, ESOL ( English as a second language), there are vocabulary games, called ***ice-breakers*** or [**icebreakers**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ice+breaker?show=0&t=1378730758),  which teachers introduce on their very first day with a new language class. Supposedly, these games are devised to help break the tension; help relax the students; add an element of fun to the class activities; and above all, give time for the nervous teacher to sort out her materials, and mentally rehearse her lesson plan before commencing.

The ice-breaking category also includes "[***getting-to-know-you***](http://whaturmissing.hubpages.com/hub/ESL-Icebreakers-Getting-to-Know-You-Games)" games whereupon each student is armed with a worksheet survey and the aim is to ask every student in class a list of questions in order to find a person who they have something in common with. This type of speaking activity is also known as ***[mingling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mingling)*** because the students have to get up, asking and answering questions while moving around the classroom as if they were at a party.

Comment: +1 for ***ice-breaker***; and it isn’t just an ESL-community term either. I’ve met it used in many situations where a bunch of people are meeting each other for the first time (from children’s parties through to grad school).

Comment: Yes, it's a borrowed term. But I first heard it in the EFL realm, I have no childhood memories of any such games being played at parties. Maybe icebreaker games started in the 80s? Or were imported from the US?

Answer (score 3):

**mixer**

As anecdotal evidence, I have heard the term "mixer" used to refer to games where the primary objective is socializing of the parties involved, with a lesser emphasis on the game itself.

[Mixer - Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mixer?q=mixer)

Comment: *Mixer* usually refers to the whole social event, not so much to specific games or activities there.

Answer (score 2):

The term *ice breaker* (sometimes spelled *icebreaker*) works for what you're describing.

[ice breaker](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/ice-breaker):

> a game or activity that is used to introduce people to each other so that they feel more relaxed together: 
>   *An ice breaker can be a useful way to start a presentation or training session.*

Answer (score 0):

In the adult world, these are called, "Team-building exercises" (because adult professionals don't play games, you know).

I don't see any reason why the term couldn't be adapted for kids when the goal (and sometimes even the game) is the same though. If you said "team-building game", I think most native speakers would understand the concept.